# Does a maiden over require all 6 balls to be bowled?

Tags: cricket, terminology

If a team is defending a total, and say in the first ball the bowler takes a wicket and the team is all-out. Will that over be considered a maiden over since no runs came from the batsman's bat and there were no bowler extras either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be considered a maiden convention is that it must be a completed over.